# Python Pandas: Get dataframe.value_counts() result as list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` and I want to get both group names and corresponding group counts as a list or numpy array. However when I convert the output to matrix I only get group counts I dont get the names. Like in the example below:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.5, 0.4, 5 , 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 ]})
  b = df['a'].value_counts()
  print(b)
```

output:

```
[0.4    2
0.5    2
0.6    1
5.0    1
Name: a, dtype: int64]
```

what I tried is `print[b.as_matrix()]`. Output:

```
[array([2, 2, 1, 1])]
```

In this case I do not have the information of corresponding group names which also I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert it to a `dict`:

```
bd = dict(b)
print(bd)
# {0.40000000000000002: 2, 0.5: 2, 0.59999999999999998: 1, 5.0: 1}
```

Don't worry about the long decimals. They're just a result of floating point representation; you still get what you expect from the dict.

```
bd[0.4]
# 2
```

Answer (score 4):

most simplest way

```
list(df['a'].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
np.c_[np.unique(df.a, return_counts=1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [270]: df
Out[270]: 
     a
0  0.5
1  0.4
2  5.0
3  0.4
4  0.5
5  0.6

In [271]: np.c_[np.unique(df.a, return_counts=1)]
Out[271]: 
array([[ 0.4,  2. ],
       [ 0.5,  2. ],
       [ 0.6,  1. ],
       [ 5. ,  1. ]])
```

We can zip the outputs from `np.unique` for list output -

```
In [283]: zip(*np.unique(df.a, return_counts=1))
Out[283]: [(0.40000000000000002, 2), (0.5, 2), (0.59999999999999998, 1), (5.0, 1)]
```

Or use `zip` directly on the `value_counts()` output -

```
In [338]: b = df['a'].value_counts()

In [339]: zip(b.index, b.values)
Out[339]: [(0.40000000000000002, 2), (0.5, 2), (0.59999999999999998, 1), (5.0, 1)]
```